# Trouble appending to a length limit if statement won't append more than one each time the function is called

Tags: python, list, if-statement, append, imgur

So I'm trying to generate Imgur links to append to a list until the list is 10000 links long, but the function only generates one link each time it's called, instead of all 10000. What's wrong?

```
import string
import random
maybe = []
def id_generator(size=7, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase):
    if len(maybe) < 10000:
        maybe.append('http://imgur.com/gallery/' + ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size)))
```

Comment: You need to loop the append call

Comment: erm, how do I do that?

Comment: See my answer for that.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `if`, a conditional statement, not a loop.

What you need is this:

```
while len(maybe) < 10000:
```

Comment: I tried that, but then the program flips a hit and tells me I reached a max amount of recursions at length 992-994

Comment: Is that the whole function? I tested it and it works fine. There shouldn't be a problem with only 10000 loops. Where are you running this?

Comment: Also, add that comment to the question, to explain that you have tried that.

Answer (score 0):

You arent looping the append part:

do this:

```
def id_generator(size=7, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase):
for i in xrange(10000):
    maybe.append('http://imgur.com/gallery/' + ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size)))
```

Comment: So this is odd because when I run the function and go to check maybe it just dies...

Comment: nevermind! it just didn't like 10000 as a number. too big of a list I guess.

Comment: Where are you running this?